# Self Referential Entity - MANY TO MANY

Tags: c#, database, database-design, entity-relationship

Just after some advice regarding this database design situation.

So I have two tables in the database.

Table 1: Patients
Table 2: Claimants

Patients holds attributes data on a private patient, so details about the person, his/her birthday, names, medical conditions, etc etc.. 
Claimants is the entity who pays on behalf of the patient, so Claimant can be a patient himself, another person, a business (who pays for work injury), private healthcare provider, government bodies etc etc..

Patients and claimants have IDs who are foreign keys in other tables such as invoices, receipts etc...

One Patient can have multiple Claimants (More than one entity can pay on his behalf), each Claimant can have multiple patients.

On further investigation, I've identified that many of the attributes of Patients and Claimants overlap as a Patient can pay for himself thus is a private Claimant.

My thinking is to merge the two tables into one and simply call it accounts and have a claimantType field to identify the type of the account, be it private, healthcare, business or government.

What potential practical drawbacks do I need to keep in mind with this change? Apart from the changing the other linked tables in database?

EDIT: Just to make it clear, There's already a junctional table PatientClaimants which basically just map the patients to the claimants. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either (a) put in an intersection table that relates patient IDs to claimant IDs, or (b) as you discussed, merge them together - but if you already have data out there that could be problematic.

You could also set up a demographics table that shows common data between patients and claimants and references an abbreviated patient/claimant table - this way you do not break your existing structure.

Comment: As a side noote - if you shifted to a shared demographics table, you could always craft a couple of views to help present your data in a way that your legacy code could work with (done this mroe than once in refactoring an app)

Comment: Hi Bob, Can you elaborate on the demographics table? How would I reference them back to the two tables?

Comment: I already have about 10K rows of Patients + Claimants but I suppose I can query and insert into a new table. The relationships are not terribly complicated. I'm just wondering if It's worth the effort.

Comment: Sure, for example, assuming you have patients and claimants (who may or may not be the same person), but may have a lot of common data - like name, etc. - You add a DemographicID to a demographics table, and in the Patients table and Claimants table, add a demographic ID that is a FK, so a single person can be both a patient and a claimant.

Comment: Thanks Bob, this gave me some food for thought. I can see that by having one demographics table would make some statistical report querying alot easier.

Answer (score 2):

**Merging** these two tables I believe is **wrong**.

A patient is always a human. So it cannot be a business or an organisation.

I believe here you have:

```
Address
=======
......

Person
=======
AddressId (FK)

BusinessEntity
==============
AddressId  (FK)

Patient
=======
PersonId (FK)

Claimant
========
PersonId  (FK)
BusinessEntityId  (FK)
```

Here PersonId or BusinessId one of them can be null.

Comment: Agreed 100%. Birthday, names, medical conditions sound specific to Patient and should probably be kept in their own table.

Comment: Hi Aliostad, I can see the advantages of your design but the trouble is that at the moment, business, organisations are not distinct in the Claimants table so I have no way of seperating and inserting them into the sub tables as I have no way of telling which claimant is a business, which is a healthcare etc... but thanks! This gave me some ideas for future designs.